# Cannot upload image using AJAX Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, image-upload

I'm trying to upload image to phpmyadmin database and have select BLOB type for image storage in database, I'm trying to upload image using jQuery but the issue is that my `new FormData(this)` is not any values in the form and due to that after going in the controller function if doesn't goes in `if condition` and moves towards else and returns the response as some error has occurred.

I have tried many different ways to pass the data but none of them is working:

- data:`new FormData(this)`,
- data: `new FormData($('#upload_image')[0])`,
- data: `{ fileName: $("input[name='imageFile']").val().split("\\").pop() }`
- data: `{  file: $("input[name='imageFile']").val() }`

**My View**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/e26d097cd9.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <br><br><br>
        <h3 class="text-center">Uploading Image Using AJAX</h3>
        <div id="message"></div>
        <form method="POST" id="upload_image" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="imageFile" id="image_file">
            <br><br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="upload" id="upload">Upload </button>
        </form>
        <div class="uploaded_image">

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bootstrap/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#upload_image').submit(function(e){
        // $('#upload_image').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            // var formData = $('#uploaded_image').serialize();
            // alert(formData);
            if($('#image_file').val() == ''){
                alert('Please Attach a File');
            }
            else{
                // alert("Hello");
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>main/ajax_upload",
                    type: "POST",
                    // data:new FormData(this),
                    data: new FormData($('#upload_image')[0]),
                    // data: {
                    //  fileName: $("input[name='imageFile']").val().split("\\").pop(),
                    //  // file: $("input[name='imageFile']").val()
                    // },
                    // data: new FormData($('#upload_image')[0]),
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processType: false,
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $('#upload').append('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>');
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#upload .fa-spinner').remove();
                        $('#uploaded_image').html(data);

                        $('#message').html(data.message);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**My Controller**

```
public function ajax_upload(){
        // echo "<script>alert('hello')</script>";
        if(isset($_FILES['image_file']["name"])){
        // if(isset($_FILES['imageFile'])){
            $config['upload_path'] = './upload/'; 
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if(!$this->upload->do_upload('imageFile')){
                // echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                $error['message'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
                echo json_encode($error);
            }
            else{
                $data = $this->upload->data();
                // echo "<img src=" . base_url() . "upload/" . $data["file_name"] . ">";
                echo '<img src="'.base_url().'upload/'.$data["file_name"].'">';
            }
        }
        else{
            $error['message'] = "An Error Occured";
            echo json_encode($error);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your data variable, you are referencing the wrong form ID.

It should be

```
data: new FormData($('#upload_image')[0]),
```

Comment: Ooh sorry that's my mistake! Thanks for letting me know but now my control in not being transferred  to my control and I'm getting an error of **"Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"** in console.

Answer (score 1):

On your ajax config, you should set the [`processData`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) to `false` to prevent the data values getting converted to a query string :

```js
                    processData: false,
```

Comment: Ok! so now i can pass my data but when i'm debugging my code so form network section I'm getting (binary) as the passed file.

Comment: I think the problem is you set the input name as `imageFile` but on the controller you get the file using `$_FILES['image_file']`, the name is different

Comment: Thank for pointing out the mistake and now i'm really close to the solution but the problem is that now it is providing me an error that **'The upload path does not appear to be valid'.** but my upload path is valid. I tried using **$config['upload_path'] = './upload/';** also but the same error is provided again and again.

Comment: If you have the `upload` folder outside CI application folder (in root folder), you could use `FCPATH` like this : `$config['upload_path'] = realpath(FCPATH . 'upload');`, and if the `upload` folder is inside the application folder, you could use `APPPATH` like : `$config['upload_path'] = realpath(APPPATH . 'upload');`

Comment: It's placed in the root folder where application, system and folders are present; and I have used **base_url() . 'upload'** and **FCPATH . 'upload'** and I print the whole file path it prints the correct file path